# PHP format date is displaying wrong

Tags: php, date, format

I'm trying to format a date from a post variable. When you type in: 05-05-2016 it will display as May 5, 2016. But when you type 05-12-2016, it will display as December 5, 2016. The format is below:

```
echo date("F d, Y", strtotime($wedding_date));
```

The format I would like is: Month Day, Year

Comment: You can try it out at: http://overtheoceanfilms.com/index_2.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date_format(date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $wedding_date), 'F d, Y');
```

and adjust 'm-d-Y' to your needs (or input).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there is an ambiguity in the input.
 So strtotime does not know what input format you delivered. 
You may consider using DateTime instead.

```
$out = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $weddingDay);
echo $out->format('F d, Y');
```